# Authentication failed for bucket "Bucket Name" for CouchbaseServer with Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, couchbase

I am trying to setup CouchbaseServer with Web Api so that I can use N1QL to fire SQL based query on NOSQL database Couchbase. But I am encountering an exception in Getting Bucket.
This is how my CouchBaseConfig looks like:

```
public static class CouchbaseConfig
    {
        private static readonly List<string> TravelSampleIndexNames = new List<string>
        {
            "def_sourceairport",
            "def_airportname",
            "def_type",
            "def_faa",
            "def_icao",
            "def_city"
        };

        public static void Register()
        {
            var couchbaseServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CouchbaseServer");
            ClusterHelper.Initialize(new ClientConfiguration
            {
                Servers = new List<Uri> { new Uri(couchbaseServer) }
            });

            var bucketName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CouchbaseTravelBucket");
            var username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CouchbaseUser");
            var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CouchbasePassword");

            EnsureIndexes(bucketName, username, password);
        }

        private static void EnsureIndexes(string bucketName, string username, string password)
        {
            var bucket = ClusterHelper.GetBucket(bucketName, password);
            var bucketManager = bucket.CreateManager(username, password);

            var indexes = bucketManager.ListN1qlIndexes();
            if (!indexes.Any(index => index.IsPrimary))
            {
                bucketManager.CreateN1qlPrimaryIndex(true);
            }

            var missingIndexes = TravelSampleIndexNames.Except(indexes.Where(x => !x.IsPrimary).Select(x => x.Name)).ToList();
            if (!missingIndexes.Any())
            {
                return;
            }

            foreach (var missingIndex in missingIndexes)
            {
                var propertyName = missingIndex.Replace("def_", string.Empty);
                bucketManager.CreateN1qlIndex(missingIndex, true, propertyName);
            }

            bucketManager.BuildN1qlDeferredIndexes();
            bucketManager.WatchN1qlIndexes(missingIndexes, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        }

        public static void CleanUp()
        {
            ClusterHelper.Close();
        }
```

But when I run the web application , I am getting the following error:

```
AuthenticationException: Authentication failed for bucket 'travel-sample']
```

[image: Snapshot of the exception]

Can anyone please help me to resolve this problem.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you debug and check if you are getting correct values of username and password from the application configuration?

Comment: Yes , I have checked. I'm getting the correct value of username and password. @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: What version of the SDK and Couchbase server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I got past this error by changing `CouchbaseConfig.Register` as follows:

```cs
public static void Register()
{
    var couchbaseServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CouchbaseServer");
    var username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CouchbaseUser");
    var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CouchbasePassword");

    ClusterHelper.Initialize(
        new ClientConfiguration
        {
            Servers = new List<Uri> { new Uri(couchbaseServer) },
        },
        new PasswordAuthenticator(username, password));

    var bucketName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CouchbaseTravelBucket");

    EnsureIndexes(bucketName, username, password);
}
```

Comment: FYI, a similar change has been [merged](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/try-cb-dotnet/commit/8854c730c556dea2cfe267841d72e2454fe48baf#diff-5c84f5eef5639ac224baaf18a2809091) into master to make this compatible with Couchbase Server 5.0.